# Pass a list to a pandas query via user input

Tags: python, pandas, search, filter

I have this dataframe of drug info and would like to filter the data based on user input.

If I explicitly state the search as follows the result are ok:

```
df = pd.read_excel("safety.xlsx")    

search = ['Lisinopril', 'Perindopril']
print(df.query('`Drug Name` in @search'))
```

But, if I try to pass the search to user input I can only enter a single drug name without error:

```
while True:
    search = input("Enter drug name...")        
    print(df.query('`Drug Name` in @search'))    
    if search == "exit":
        break
```

So I would like for the user to be able to enter a list of drugs, not one at a time. If I enter Lisinopril, Perindopril the result is 'Empty DataFrame'

Terminal:

```
Enter drug name...Lisinopril
    Drug Name                                                U&E    C
0  Lisinopril  Before commencing, at 1-2 weeks after starting...  NaN

Enter drug name...Lisinopril, Perindopril
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Drug Name, U&E, C]
Index: []
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you thought of maybe creating a .xlsx file on entry? This way the user would be able to enter the data which would then be saved for later usage and you can simply use the read_excel function?

Comment: The excel file wont need to be written to, only referenced from and the search terms would always be different and maybe up to 12 different drugs.

Comment: Have you tried appending the drug name to the list? Seems that's the only difference between the two code blocks.

Comment: Okay, from the terminal output you've added I think you need to parse the user input. I would do `search = search.strip().split(",")`. This would split the string by commas and strip() would remove any whitespace you have.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to query multiple fields in the dataframe, you should append the user input to an array.

```
query = []
in = input("Drug name: ")
query.append(in)
print(df.query('`Drug Name` in @search'))
```

If you would like to query a single drug multiple times you should use the `==` notation in the query.

```
user_input = input("Drug name: ")
subframe = df.query('`Drug Name` == @user_input'))
```